# Are there macros for ocaml that remove code from executable with some compiler options?

Tags: ocaml, preprocessor-directive

I'm writing code in OCaml where I do some stuff when a verbose flag is on.

```
if verbose then
  do_stuff ();
```

When `verbose` is `false` then this stuff is not executed. However, I'd like to move the flag to some kind of compiler options and not even execute the `if verbose` check, much like gcc compiler option `-DFLAG` and `#ifdef FLAG` in the code would do in C. How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: It might be possible to do that using a ppx.

Comment: there are ppxs for conditional execution. For example https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/ppx_const/